# Generate a string with random words

Tags: c#, random, permutation

I need to write a function which will randomize some words of my string. For example:

```
[Hello|Hi] guys. This is my [code|string]
```

The function should return:

`Hello guys. This is my code`

or

`Hi guys. This is my string`

Comment: This is called permutations...

Comment: You want it sometimes to say "Hello" and sometimes "Hi" randomly, and the same for "code" and "string"?

Comment: Yes­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a random number generator like this:

`var rand = new Random();`

As for parsing your string and getting all of the options, I suggest you look into `System.Text.RegularExpressions`

The other answers so far have just shown how you can get a random string if you already have one or two options for the different placeholders. Those are fine, but pretty boring and tedious to write out. It's much better to write a parser that can take a random string "template" like the OP gave, and use that to generate the random strings.

Here is a quick one I put together:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace StackOverLoadTest {
static class Program {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        var s = new RandomString("[Hey|Hi] guys. [I|You|We|He|She] should [walk] to the [park|field|farm] sometime [today|tomorrow|next week].");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}

public class RandomString {
    private Random _rnd = new Random();
    private static Regex _rex = new Regex(@"\[ ( \|?  (?<option>[^]|]+) )+ \]", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
    string _template;
    public RandomString(string template) {
        _template = template;
    }
    public override string ToString() {
        return _rex.Replace(_template, GetRandomOption);
    }
    public string GetRandomOption(Match m) {
        var options = m.Groups["option"].Captures;
        int choice = _rnd.Next(0, options.Count);
        return options[choice].Value;
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, you use create a new RandomString object with the template. Then simply call the ToString() function as many time as you want, and each time you get a new random permutation of the options.

You can use any number of placeholders with any number of options (except 0).
The string template I used in this example was:

`"[Hey|Hi] guys.  [I|You|We|He|She] should [walk] to the [park|field|farm]  sometime [today|tomorrow|next week]."`

Running the code above, I got the following results:

`Hey guys.  I should walk to the park sometime today.

Hi guys.  We should walk to the farm sometime today.

Hi guys.  He should walk to the field sometime next week.

Hey guys.  You should walk to the park sometime next week.

Hi guys.  She should walk to the farm sometime next week.

Hey guys.  We should walk to the field sometime tomorrow.

Hi guys.  I should walk to the farm sometime today.

Hey guys.  He should walk to the field sometime tomorrow.

Hi guys.  You should walk to the park sometime next week.

Hi guys.  I should walk to the farm sometime today.`

Comment: Best and most pluggable answer.

Comment: Oh hey, nice use of `Replace`. Much simpler than what I was going for.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, you can probably work on the regex a little more. It is not quite what I wanted, but it allows multiple captures for the "options" within a single match. This is what gives the regex the power to work with an indefinite number of options for each placeholder instead of just two (or any other fixed number).

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
private string randArr(String[] _arr)
{
    Random _rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.GetHashCode());
    return _arr[_rnd.Next(_arr.length)];
}
```

just call it giving your array for string values. Like this :

```
String.Format("{0} guys. This is my {1}", randArr(["Hello","Hi"]), randArr(["code","string"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int val = rand.Next(0, 100);
Console.WriteLine(
    "{0} guys. This is my {1}",

    val >= 50 ? "Hi" : "Hello",
    val < 50 ? "code" : "string");
```

I gave a 50%-50% chance to what word is written so that's the `>= 50` & `< 50` you see. **you can change that.**

If you wanted to randomize each word for it's own and not the complete sentence (the code above gives you only 2 variations) just mess around with the code or comment me to modify it.

Notes:

It's actually not 50%-50%. I didn't want to confuse, but if you want it like that, the first condition should be `>= 49`*

The syntax for the condition (`condition ? statement : statement`) is called *[ternary if operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)*.

Comment: what happens if val is exactly 50?

Comment: @FlorisPrijt True, I'll edit it right away! thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: This binds the two outcomes. You'll always have Hello + string OR Hi + code. The other combinations will never be shown because you use the same random value for both.

Comment: @Flater As I said in the second paragraph. I wasn't sure so I left it to the OP to comment me. Are you sure that's what he wants?

Comment: Either way, your option shows the two results that are not mentioned in the original question, the two outputs that are specifically requested are impossible to receive using this snippet. No offense though, it's solid programming in general :)

Comment: @Flater I didn't really care about that, I did care for the logic (I hope you agree that it's valid). I'll edit it tho if it bothers someone enough to comment about it. Thank you of course.